# How to set alarm or push notification

Tags: android, service, push-notification, alarm

I am trying to make a reminder application on Android. I have taken data from the user and saved in a database. How do I trigger an alarm or push notification on  user entered date?

Comment: and obviously new to stackoverflow too. plz take a look on the "how to ask a question"-page :-)

Comment: i have taken date from user on which want to set notification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create push notification, you have to register on console API. but I can't post link , because of low reputation and get your own key. Personally I used this tutorial to create and handle push notification.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/
but I can't understand why do you need it to alarm user.
To implement alarm after some elapsed time, you can create Service:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
There you can create your own alarm or use one of the standard. Sorry, I can't provide code example, because your question is too general.

Comment: after google i found some hint by using services we can do. but still i have problem .Any one have experience on this please share!!!

Comment: Any solution for this still i am waiting .

Comment: I found some tutorial how to use service: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/  about alarm - a short snippet is here  http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/ . Try something and let me know about some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the information into the Calendar application with the appropriate settings and you will get an alarm when the event occurs.

Comment: Sorry, but that is left as an exercise for the reader - one hint, the format of the file you'll insert is .ics

Comment: i have not inserted  any file, i am taking date from user and inserting in the database, and i want push notification or alarm on user enterd date!